# Android - phonegap loadUrl with hash tag

Tags: android, cordova

I recently upgraded a project from a very old phonegap release to cordova 1.7.0 and it is trying to load a web page into the webView using loadUrl with a url like this:

http://www.example.com/blog-page-123#showComment=45

but it throws an Uncaught ReferenceError: showComment is not defined at http://www.example.com/blog-page-123#showComment=45:1

What's up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably running into issues:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17535

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17327

Go star 'em.

Comment: Thanks.  Bad news - but still a valid answer.